# How to synchronize a thread to process data while another fetches from an API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, etl

I want to fetch data from an API in batches, and then process that data. While the CPU is idle during the download of the current batch, it would be nice if another thread can be processing the data from the previous thread.

The following uses `n` threads to download a batch and process it. The thing I'm observing is that all `n` threads will download their batch at the same time, then they all process the data at the same time. Not quite what I want. Any suggestions?

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading


thread_local = threading.local()

def fetch_async(batch_size, threads=3):
    def fetch(offset):
        print(f'Starting download offset={offset}, id={threading.get_ident()}')
        res = download(offset, batch_size)
        return process(res)


    print(f'Fetching async: batch_size={batch_size}')
    offsets = list(range(0, total + batch_size, batch_size))

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        res = executor.map(fetch, offsets)

    # materialize + flatten iterator
    res = list(res)
    return [y for x in res for y in x]
```

What I see in the logs is the statement `Starting download` print in rapid succession for each thread, then a pause while the download and processing take place. Then again, a few of the statements again basically at the same time, etc. The download portion takes 3-5 seconds to complete. I've experimented with 3, 4, 8, and 12 threads. Same behavior, and about the same amount of time to complete the entire process (making ~100 individual API calls).

Comment: If you start all threads at the same time and give then the same amount of work, you can expect them to be more or less synchronized and finish at the same time. Or maybe you always want a single piece of data to be downloaded at the same time, and a single piece of data to be processed at the same time, while both could run in parralel ?

Comment: Most of the concurrent processing is occurring when the `res = list(res)` statement executes and it blocks until that all of it is finished.

Comment: @martineau that doesn't seem to be the case because if I simply return `res` without converting it to a list or doing anything else to it, the whole process still take about the same amount of time (and the log statements happen in the same way).

Comment: That just moves the blocking to the `return [y for x in res for y in x]` where each iteratation of the `for x in res` part blocks until the next one becomes available.

Comment: No, what I do is `return res` right after the `with` block. I do nothing else with that object. In other words, the value of each element in the iterator returned by `executor.map` seems to be the evaluated response of each call to `fetch`. You are telling me that those calls are lazily evaluated by the iterator, but that doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: To validate both of our claims, I put calls to `datetime.datetime.now()` around my calls to flatten the response of `executor.map` at the end, and it turns out that my `list(res)` and `[y for x in res for y in x]` combined only take ~20ms (`{"before": "2020-02-05 15:14:15.318021, "after": "2020-02-05 15:14:15.323493"}`)